# Display image instead of text

Tags: php, joomla, html-select

I am very new in php. I have a site with the CMS joomla 3.6. 
In the register of a third part component I have a select box to the members inform his gender. In the html of the page, returns the text 'male' and 'female'. 
What I need is to replace the text 'male' and 'female' with images.

In the PHP file I have this:

```
public function getFieldData($field) {
    $options = array("COM_COMMUNITY_MALE" => "COM_COMMUNITY_MALE", "COM_COMMUNITY_FEMALE" => "COM_COMMUNITY_FEMALE");
    $value = strtoupper($field['value']);
    if ( isset($options[$value])) {
        return JText::_($options[$value]);
    }else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

So, I know that the second "COM_COMMUNITY_MALE" and "COM_COMMUNITY_FEMALE" are the output html and I have tried to replace them with that code `<img src="image/image.png"/>`. But no luck, can someone tell me what is the path to do this?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: "the second "COM_COMMUNITY_MALE" and "COM_COMMUNITY_FEMALE" are the output" - this bit is unclear, please specify. Also I suggest you to show the non-working code and describe its expected and actual behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a dropdown box, and, for example, `COM_COMMUNITY_MALE` is the value and the label of one of the options in that dropdown box, and you can't have a value in a dropdown that is HTML code (for example, an `img` tag). You will need to review your requirements.